# How to group array Hear?

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

Before I have used three function to display the data but now i have written only query to all the data and make it as a array grouping.because i want to display all the data using one big array...
I have grouped array like this:

```
                        $menu_array=array();
       foreach($this->getArticlesByLabels as $k)
        {
            $menu_array[$k["label_name"]][]=$k;
        }
```

From that, I got ouput like this:

```
                 Array
                 (
[DON\'T MISS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Ram Charan\'s GAV movie: Live updates from movie hall
        [1] => breaking news article 1
        [2] => This is dont mis articles 1 
    )

[WEB EXCLUSIVE] => Array
    (
        [0] => This is the web exclusive article 1 .....
    )

[NON STOP] => Array
    (
        [0] => This is the non stop article 2 ...
    )

 )
```

I want to make it as a :

```
  Array
 (
[0]=>Array{

   [DON\'T MISS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Ram Charan\'s GAV movie: Live updates from movie hall
        [1] => breaking news article 1
        [2] => This is dont mis articles 1 
    )
)
[1]=>Array(
      [WEB EXCLUSIVE] => Array
    (
        [0] => This is the web exclusive article 1 .....
    )
 )
[2]=>Array(
[NON STOP] => Array
    (
        [0] => This is the non stop article 2 ...
    )
)
  )
```

because i want make foreach for total array that way...
please help me in this..

$this->getArticlesByLabels out put is..I am giving that array format only I cant post total array because that is very big....

```
   Array
   (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 108347
        [Category_id] => 11204
        [title] => Ram Charan\'s GAV movie: Live updates from movie hall
    )
 [1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 108346
        [Category_id] => 10
        [title] => breaking news article 1
        [text_data] => aafasfasdfasdfasdfasdf
    )
 [2]
  .
  .
[20]
   )
```

Comment: Can you paste `print_r($this->getArticlesByLabels)` output?

Comment: yes See the post..i have posted.. - alu

Comment: i think need `label_name` in `$this->getArticlesByLabels`.

Comment: in that array so many values are there.so label_name also there ...you can use label_name field...

Comment: [Such a thing?](http://pastebin.com/abnBgEyd)